# open new window as popup [html, js]

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, window

I'm not sure how to describe it properly but I will try.
Currently I have a page with stuff in it and I want to have a button that when pressed it will open a new window with more stuff in it that's part of the same "entity", meaning I want to transfer variables from the 2nd "pop-up" window to the first.
The idea is that I need a lot of space and one page isn't enough (no scrolling). So I want to have more divs in this new "pop-up" window. (If I make a regular div to be the popup I won't be able to drag it around outside the window)

In the following image is kinda what I want to have (The 2 monitors are just to make my request clearer)

All responses are appreciated

**I use pure JS*
[image]

Comment: I don't think that's possible unless you modify the browser or something.

Comment: Not sure how I'd do it in pure JS. I think you could probably pass a redux state tree to a new window if you wanted to? But without any of the bells and whistles of modern JS development, your option is basically "Reinvent the wheel"

Comment: I can't be the first to have this problem. And it's a useful thing to be able to do, so I'd think it'd be possible (albeit not as easy as setting a class and be done with it).
So then my only option is to just make it a draggable div I guess?

Comment: Can I at least open a new tab/window but that it can communicate with the first one so that when I enter values in the second window it updates the first window